# Why does Infinite loop occurs while reversing the linked list using recursion

Tags: pointers, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I am a beginner in data structures. Lets assume that I have a linked list of 5 elements. I was writing the below code to reverse the linked list using recursion:

```
void reverse (node* p)
{
    if (p->next == NULL)
    {
        head = p;
        return;
    }
    reverse (p->next);
    node* q = p->next;
    q->next = p;
    p->next = NULL;
}
```

In the above code, head node is passed initially as an argument. This code runs well;but the question is why are we using the line?

```
p->next = NULL;
```

If I did not add that line, it becomes an infinite loop. But even if that line is not added, p->next is assigned with the previous node's address in the following stack unwinding. So why does it cause an infinite loop if that line is not added?

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to do this exercise. That's not how you should do anything really (mutating a variable that wasn't passed into the function)

Comment: Think of it like a military draftee in line. Everyone is facing east. If you tell them to turn about-face, then the first guy (west most) will have to face nobody. This is that line. Removing that line makes the first node (now last) still face the second node (now second from last).

Comment: @alvits: still that changes in following stack unwinding

Comment: I think you are forgetting that the initial entry to the function will be the last to return. With this in mind, if you don't set `p->next` to `NULL`, where should it point to? Isn't the last node in a list supposed to point to `NULL` to designate end of list?

Comment: Remember, the initial entry to the function is handling the head node which becomes the tail node on exit. And it's the last one to exit.

Comment: If these comments can't convince you, I suggest you run trace or step it on debugger. You may post the result of debugging for future readers to see,

Comment: @alvits: Thanks, alvits. I think u helped me get it. It is the last data that causes the problem. Till it gets to the last node, it works as expected. After that the first and the second node loops pointing to each other infinitely